# Who is the firstborn of God and why is he called the firstborn?

Tags: torah-study

Then say to Pharaoh, ‘This is what the LORD says: Israel is my firstborn son, and I told you, “Let my son go, so he may worship me.” But you refused to let him go; so I will kill your firstborn son.’” Exodus 4:22-23

Why is Israel or Jacob the firstborn? Why not Isaac? Why not Abraham? Why is Israel or Jacob exalted above the patriarchs? Is it possible that this verse has a deeper meaning and understanding to it? If yes, what is that deeper meaning and understanding?

Comment: At a simple level, that which the *benei yisrael* are called firstborn here can only be with regard to the other nations, otherwise relative to who are they firstborn? If so, the *passuk* seems to allude to that which the *benei  yisrael* are the *edim* of Hashem to the world, which function they cannot fulfill as slaves to Pharoh.

Comment: @pcoz I understand that would be the first explanation that comes to mind. But it still makes me question why Israel is exalted above Isaac and Abraham? After all, God makes a covenant with Abraham before he makes a covenant with the nation of Israel and the nation of Israel comes from Abraham just as much as it comes from Jacob. If we say yeah but ultimately the promise continues through Isaac and then Jacob, not the other sons, what do we do with the fact that later God abandons Israel and then only chooses Judah? Read Psalms 78.

Comment: The ter *Israel* means the nation as a whole. Judah is merely the tribe of the king, while Israel is everyone of all the tribes. Hashem does not *abandon* Israel and later choose Judah.

Comment: @sabbahillel You say Ha-Shem does not later abandon Israel and choose Judah. But that is exactly what God does! Read Psalm 78. Verse 59: He rejected Israel completely. Verse 68: but he chose the tribe of Judah, Mount Zion, which he loved.

Comment: @Mordecai אין בן דוד בא אלא בהיסח הדעת Yaakov was *mesiach da'as* from the world, therefore he was *koneh* it.

Comment: @Mordecai, you are misunderstanding Psalm 78. It is referring to the desctruction of the Tabernacle in Shiloh and the choice of Judah as the home of the Sanctuary. It doesn't mean rejection of Israel as the chosen people.  See verse 71 of the Psalm. David of Judah, is chosen as the king to be sheperd for all of Israel "G-d's nation" and "G-d's lot," not just Judah:  "לִ֭רְעוֹת בְּיַעֲקֹ֣ב עַמּ֑וֹ וּ֝בְיִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל נַחֲלָתֽוֹ"

Answer (score 1):

Some commentators remark on the two prongs of the question (in what sense first born and why Israel)

Rashi explains:

> בני בכרי [ISRAEL IS] MY SON, MY FIRSTBORN — The term בכור “firstborn” denotes high dignity as, (Psalms 89:28) “I also will appoint him a בכור” (which is explained by the following words, “the highest of the kings of the earth”). This is the literal meaning; a Midrashic comment is: Here (in these words) the Holy One, blessed be He, set His seal to the sale of the birthright which Jacob had purchased from Esau (Genesis Rabbah 63:14).

The Chizkuni adds:

> until Aaron became a priest the Temple service was meant to be performed by the firstborn. This is why I demand that you release My firstborn son to perform the service before me in the desert.

Ibn Ezra writes:

> AND THOU SHALT SAY. The meaning of Israel is My son, My first-born i.e., verse 23. is: the ancestors of this nation were the first to serve Me. I therefore take pity on this nation as a father pities a son who serves him. You took him for a perpetual slave. I will therefore kill your first-born son.

There are other explanations including the question of sanctification of the group which didn't happen to the people under the auspices of Abraham and Isaac.